# Trouble passing and handling data from HTML form to external JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

I am having trouble with the passing of data from the HTML to the JS script, whenever I click submit nothing happens, the aim is for the user to input a date into a form which is then sent to the javascript script and that date will be compared to the current date and then work out the number of days / weeks difference between the two and then returned back to the HTML page, here is what I have so far;

HTML Code

```
<script src="DandT.js">
<input type="date" name="dd/mm/yyyy"`id="uniqueID" value="datetime" />
<button type="button" onclick="proccessFormData()">Submit</button>
```

JS Code

```
function processFormData(){

    var frm_element = document.getElementById('uniqueID');
    var current = new date();
    var timeDiff = frm_element.getTime() - current.getTime();

    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);

    return weeks * days;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: try document.getElementById('uniqueID').value;

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="date" name="dd/mm/yyyy" id="uniqueID" value="datetime" />
<button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
<script src="DandT.js">
```

JS

```
  function processFormData(){
    var inputDate = document.querySelector('#uniqueID');
    var timeDiff = inputDate.getTime() - Date.now();

    var seconds = ~~(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = ~~(seconds / 60);
    var hours = ~~(minutes / 60);
    var days = ~~(hours / 24);
    var weeks = ~~(days / 7);

    return weeks * days; // this only RETURNS the data, this won't actually trigger a form submit.
  }

  document.querySelector('.submit').addEventListener(processFormData);
```

If you wan't to trigger a form submit with the new data, then you should either do manually an AJAX call or inject the computed value into a hidden `input` and trigger a form submit (`form.submit()`).

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out to get it working i had to use

var usrDate = new Date(uniqueID.value);

thanks for all your helpful suggestions guys!